# Nutch plugin development

Tags: eclipse, ant, plugins, nutch

The nutch wiki has instructions on [how to build nutch plugins](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample-0%2e9), but only if you download the entire nutch source tree and put it in there, below $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin.  I don't want my source code mixed in their subversion tree, I want it in my src/com/xcski git repository.  And I shouldn't have to download the source code for nutch just to build a plugin, I should just be able to stick a jar in my Eclipse build path and go.

So basically, I'm looking for what to put in my ant build.xml file and what to put into Eclipse to write and build my plugin.  And keep in mind that I'm a total ant neophyte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing of Nutch, but from looking at the wiki, it doesn't seem that your plugin will actually depend upon any parts of the nutch source code. The plugin seems to be pretty much standalone. I'm guessing that they recommend you put it there so it will be bundled along with the rest of the project when built.

Have you tried to create a plugin from the **Required Files** step onwards and then taking your built plugin and putting it wherever Nutch expects? (you might have to create a hello world plugin to see where that is)

Comment: In experimenting, it appears that in spite of the fact that the other plugins are in nutch-1.0.job, I still need the entire $NUTCH-HOME/plugins directory, and so I put my plugin there.  Thanks.